# .bashrc Error- command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I was doing some stuff in the terminal with .bashrc and I started to get an error right after every time I open terminal and it keeps staying that situation until I do <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

This is exactly what I see every time when I open terminal:

```
?\udcf7\udcca\udcd5\udcfewD\udcba\udcc4\udcf9\udc93\udcc3ڍ%\udcaeݞl\udcb0l\udcd8~\udcb3?vF-Jwx: command not found

VimCrypt~01!X\udca0oudc8f\udca1\udc85\udcb4\udcf1c\udce8KA\udcad\udcd2\udce6
\udce4*^u\udc84+o\udcf8\udcb8r\udcc5\udcc6WK^嬱: command not found

O\udcfd\udcc5I\udccbNeC\udc84: command not found

bash: /home/faruksimsekli/.bashrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: /home/faruksimsekli/.bashrc: line 3: `���?�������7�V���o5ؚ-1W���]�fHel�CO>zسU��j�-�֦A��B>��pR�⚔P
                         ������)������%���#s,�(5~L��fo:(��re���a�
                                                                      0C+��؟�[ML��r�d'

faruksimsekli@7:~$ \udca9\udcb4\udce1x\udca4\udc9d\udc92svcl\udc85v\udc85\udccbc\udcb6u\udc8d\udcf1\udcc4: command not found
```

Comment: What did you do? It looks like .bashrc is filled with garbage, so my suggestion would be to remove it and recreate it: `mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old; cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/` - this will give you the default `.bashrc` for Ubuntu.

Comment: Why is that binary junk in your `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Cyrus that's what vidarlo's `mv` command does

Comment: You edited the file with LibreOffice or something similar, right? And then said "Yes, save it as *.odt with pretty formatting and neat fonts." Don't do that.

Comment: @vidarlo I did what you said. It is OK now. I probably changed or added something to the file mistakenly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @waltinator VimCrypt is a hint: used vim, and :X. Note capital X. Lower case x exits vim - upper case encrypts...

Comment: @PerlDuck No, I did with vim. And messed up then :d

Comment: @FarukŞimşekli see my answer for what you did :) You encrypted it - and if you remember the passphrase, you can decrypt it...

Comment: Having a Vim-encrypted `~/.bashrc` will break your `bash` - `bash` wants `~/.bashrc` to be an unencrypted text file, and doesn't know how to run some random decrypter programs before reading `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What probably happend is this:

The user used vim on the file, as given by the fact that `VimCrypt` is shown in the text. When running vim, you can exit vim with `:x` - or encrypt with `:X`. Note that the former is lower case, the latter is upper case.

This would have encrypted the file upon save, rendering it as a garbled binary mess.

The easiest way out is to simply replace it by the standard Ubuntu `.bashrc`

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old ; cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

This will backup your current `.bashrc` as `.bashrc.old`

If you remember the encryption key used you can upen it in vim again. Enter the correct passphrase, and type `:X` and press enter twice (giving a blank pass phrase) and save with `:wq` - this will restore the file if you do remember the passphrase.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware htat `vim` can do encryption. /// The passphrase is probably something like `:q<ESC>:<ESC><ESC>:q!` ;-)

Comment: Thats what I end up with in my config files whenever I use vim...